# Изменение строки функцией

Tags: javascript, строки, функции

Задание заключается в том, что в функцию поступает значение a2b3, а она должна возвращать aabbb и наоборот. Часть с наоборот я сделала, а вот первая часть у меня не получается.

```js
function compress(uncompressStr) {
  let arr = uncompressStr.split('');
  let result = {}; // хэш создан для того, чтобы в него записать как ключ название буквы, а как значение - количество букв
  let compressed = '';
  //Метод forEach используется для перебора массива.
  arr.forEach(function(letter) {
    if (letter in result) {
      result[letter]++;
    } else {
      result[letter] = 1;
    }
  });
  for (letter in result) {
    //присваивание со сложением
    compressed += letter + result[letter];
  }
  console.log(compressed);

}
compress('a');
compress('aaa');
compress('aabbb');
compress('aaabcc');

function uncompress(compressStr) {
  let result = {};
}
uncompress('a1');
uncompress('a5');
uncompress('a2b3');
uncompress('a2b1c3');
```

Comment: А допускаются любые буквы или только a-b-c ?

Comment: Допускаются любые буквы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function compress(uncompressStr) {
  let arr = uncompressStr.split('');
  let result = {}; // хэш создан для того, чтобы в него записать как ключ название буквы, а как значение - количество букв
  let compressed = '';
  //Метод forEach используется для перебора массива.
  arr.forEach(function(letter) {
    if (letter in result) {
      result[letter]++;
    } else {
      result[letter] = 1;
    }
  });
  for (letter in result) {
    //присваивание со сложением
    var count = result[letter];
    while (count > 9) {
      compressed += letter + "9";
      count -= 9;
    }
    compressed += letter + count;
  }
  console.log(compressed);
  return compressed;
}

function uncompress(compressStr) {
  var result = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < compressStr.length; i += 2) {
    result += compressStr[i].repeat(+compressStr[i + 1]);
  }
  
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
uncompress('a1');
uncompress('a5');
uncompress('a2b3');
uncompress('a2b1c3');

uncompress(compress('aaaaaaaaaa'))
uncompress(compress('abc'))
```

Comment: `uncompress(compress('aaaaaaaaaa'))`? (предположим, что в `compress` есть соответствующий `return`)

Comment: @Yaant предположил, добавил

Comment: Э... `uncompress(compress('abc'))`???